# Ionic SQLite -- check if database exists

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying out Ionic framework. I need to store some data in the Android SQLite. So, I want to open or create a database and if database didn't exist before, populate it with some data.

Here it says I use `create` method even if the database already exists:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

So I wrote a class:

```
export class Database {
  private sqlite: SQLite;
  private database: SQLiteObject = null;

  constructor() {
    this.sqlite = new SQLite();
  }

  private open_db() {
    return this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'data.db',
        location: 'default'
    })
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.database = db;
        return db.sqlBatch([...some sql inserts and create tables...]);
    });
  });

  public all() {
    return this.open_db().then(() => this.database.executeSql("SELECT ...something...", []));
  }
```

Now, how do I call the db.sqlBatch only when database is actually **created**, not just opened? 
And yes, this code throws random exception without reasonable explanation that could be seen in logcat, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the openDatabase command instead of create. This will create the database if it doesn't exist.

Try following this article

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/

Also I would recommend use this command at the start of  $ionicPlatform.ready and save it in some global variable this way you can access it any time in the application. I have been using sqlite plugin with ionic v1. Above link will help you integrating it with ionic v2.

Comment: I wonder if this still works in ionic 3. The doc doesn't mention anythng about `openDatabase` method. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

Comment: @Devaroop I think as per the official documentation at github. "openDatabase" is the right approach. I haven't worked with an ionic 3 application as of yet. So I can't be sure. 
https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage